# Show non-numerical variables / columns in hover text

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have this code to create a plot and this dataframe

```
df2.dtypes
Out[464]: 
Device            category
time        datetime64[ns]
Path              category
variable            object
value              float64
path              category
dtype: object



df3 = df2.query('variable==@signals').groupby('path').first() 

fig_general = px.scatter(df3
                          , x = "time"
                          , y = 'value'
                          , custom_data = ['Path']
                          , color = 'Device'
                          , symbol = 'variable'
                          , hover_name = "Path"
                          , opacity = 0.6
                          , template = 'plotly_dark'
                          , marginal_y = "rug"
                          )
fig_general.update_layout(
                           transition_duration = 500
                          , autosize = True
                          , height = 700
                          , hovermode = 'closest'
                          )
fig_general.update_traces(marker = dict(
                                        size = 14
                                        )
                            , hovertemplate="<br>".join([
                                                        "Device: %{Device}"
                                                        , "variable': {symbol}"     
                                                        , "time: %{x}"
                                                        , "value': %{y}"
                                                    ])
                          )
```

And I would like to show `variable` and `Device` in the hover text but it is only shown as text itself. `time` and `value` is working properly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add Device data to the `customdata` like so:

```
fig_general.update_traces(marker=dict(size=14),
                          customdata=df3[['variable', 'Device']].values,
                          hovertemplate="<br>".join([
                              "Device: %{customdata[1]}",
                              "variable: %{customdata[0]}",
                              "time: %{x}",
                              "value: %{y}",
                          ])
                          )
```

Comment: @Ben , you are so welecome